# Problema com autoComplete Primefaces

Tags: java-ee, jsf, primefaces

Tenho um `<p:autoComplete>` funcionando, e tenho um `commandButton` que abre um `dialog` para que eu possa fazer um novo cadastro. O `dialog` abre, eu preencho os campos porém na hora de salvar essa exceção é lançada:

> GRAVE: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.ouvidoria.bean.AssuntoConverter.getAsObject(AssuntoConverter.java:31)

O erro acontece  na classe que utilizo para fazer a conversão  para que possa utilizar o `autoComplete`. Creio que está assim pois ao clicar no botão salvar ocorreu uma requisição ajax e como esse campo estava vazio o erro ocorreu.

Quando coloco um `process="@this"` no botão salvar o erro para porém o objeto que preencho fica `null`, por exemplo se no `imputText` coloco o `value="ouvidoriaBean.ouvidoria.telefone"` na hora que clico em salvar esse valor chega `null`. O que pode estar acontecendo e como posso resolver esse problema?

Botão salvar

```
<p:commandButton value="Salvar"
    style="margin-left:28%;margin-top:30px;width:45%"
    actionListener="#{ouvidoriaBean.salvarOuvidoria}" update=":frmPrin" />
```

Classe Conversora

```
@FacesConverter("assunto")
public class AssuntoConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        System.out.println("CODIGO: " + value);
        Integer codigo = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("getAsObject: " + value);
            codigo = Integer.valueOf(value);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        }

        List<Assunto> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        AssuntoDAO assuntoDAO = new AssuntoDAO();
        lista = assuntoDAO.listar();
        for (Assunto a : lista) {
            if (codigo.equals(a.getCodigo())) {
                return a;

            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value != null && !value.equals("")) {
            Assunto assunto = (Assunto) value;
            System.out.println("Testinho: " + assunto);
            return String.valueOf(assunto.getCodigo());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Método do `autoComplete` que fica no Bean:

```
public List<Assunto> sugerirAssunto(String consulta) {
        List<Assunto> assuntosSugeridos = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Assunto> listaAssunto = new ArrayList<>();
        try {

            AssuntoDAO assuntoDAO = new AssuntoDAO();
            listaAssunto = assuntoDAO.listar();
            for (Assunto assunto : listaAssunto) {
                if (assunto.getAssunto().toLowerCase().startsWith(consulta.toLowerCase())) {
                    assuntosSugeridos.add(assunto);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgErro("Erro ao listar Assuntos: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return assuntosSugeridos;
    }
```

Auto Complete:

```
<p:autoComplete id="assunto" value="#{ouvidoriaBean.assunto}"
    completeMethod="#{ouvidoriaBean.sugerirAssunto}"
    forceSelection="true" converter="assunto" var="a"
    itemLabel="#{a.assunto}" itemValue="#{a}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Techies**,

Separa o `dialog` que você precisa em outro form, e atualiza apenas ele quando precisar mantendo o estado do resto da página, ficaria algo como:

```
<h:form id="formAutoComplete">
<p:autoComplete id="assunto" value="#{ouvidoriaBean.assunto}"
    completeMethod="#{ouvidoriaBean.sugerirAssunto}"
    forceSelection="true" converter="assunto" var="a"
    itemLabel="#{a.assunto}" itemValue="#{a}" />
</h:form>

<h:form id="formDialog">
 //ai você processa apenas este e mantem o resto
 <p:dialog></p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Outra coisa que faço é separar os `forms`, não sei se isso é má prática, porém separo as responsabilidades de quem eu quero manter o estado.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda @Wellington Avelino

Comment: @Techies, tranquilo